# Mocha tests in browser to output xunit reports

Tags: mocha.js

I'm running a set of tests with mocha and i need the tests to run in the browser, therefore ; i'm doing this :

mocha.setup('bdd')

the tests do run fine in the browser, but i need this to be executed in jenkins. I must run the tests in the browser and i'm trying to get the reporter to output xunit reports .
i've tried the xunit-file package and another one called "mocha-multi" , it looks like browser tests only support the html reporter. Is there a way to output both the xunit and browser reports? or at least to execute the tests in the browser and report xunit results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there is no way to have two reporters if you're running the tests in the browsers and not in node js. After digging into mocha,i realized that there is a tests results variable as part of the mocha objects that you can instantiate in the browser. You need to use this to actually access the resutls and write the report yourself.